# How to set an user agent and connection timeout for jsoup in android

Tags: java, android, html-parsing, jsoup, user-agent

I was trying to extract some tweets from `mobile.twitter.com` in an android, and as a result I get a mixed html document. After some searches I realized that I need to set an user agent.

My aim is to set a default user agent which would work not only for me, but also for other users who would use my application.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://mobile.twitter.com/").userAgent(...).get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who might be interested there is an easy way for getting default user agent if you are on Android 2.1 or above.

There is a system property called `http.agent`, which can be used to retrieve the User-Agent string.

My code would then turn to:

```
String userAgent = System.getProperty("http.agent");
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://mobile.twitter.com/").userAgent(userAgent).get();
```